# String Compression Class

Tags: php, compression

I am trying to make a String compression system that could compress string with often used word in it.

But i have no idea on how i could make the logic work.

I was thinking of replacing world that apear often by a simple <1> and put that word in a array so that when we a reading the string we can see that <1> should be the first word in the array or some what.

But that is not my problem at the current moment.

Im trying to figure out how i could actually calculate how many time this word is appearing.
and i can't really use an explode(' ',$str); and check how many time it is there since i would like to check not only world but everything such as if there is allways a space between two world i would like to have them to store in my array also.

All of that in the idea of compressing a string.

Im am not looking for code tho, Im am simply trying to find a good logic i could make this work
Any one have an idea of how i could achieve that.

Thanks for any comment/awnser

Comment: [str_word_count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)

Comment: Could not work since if there is a space between two world it wont calculate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is a sliding window...  Hopefully you are using small strings :)

So, let's say your string was.

"Joey Novak Needs More Reputation :)"

We start with a 10 character string, and search the string for other instances of that string.  So the first 10 character string would be "Joey Novak", Then we search the remainder of the string for that string.  If we find one, awesome! We replace it with the marker (<1> works.) and search again, if we don't, we move on to the next string, which would be "oey Novak " and do the same, etc...  When we finish with all the 10 character strings, we move on to 9 character, and work our way down.  Since the marker is 3 characters long, you only need to go to 4 character strings.

Joey

Comment: ! actually this is smart, I dont know why i didn't think of this earlier since i already used a similar way for matching Model Number from one site to an other Any how Thanks! It may sound stupid but now i have really good idea of how i could do things.. lol Thanks!